# Find a String in an Array

Tags: performance, c, search

This program is used to get names and numbers of N person, print out the numbers of a person. Please help me improve this code.

Additional Question:

To avoid a very long name that exceeds char's size, I limit it to 255. Is there a better way?

To avoid buffer, I included a space before % sign when using scanf and not use getchar(). Is there a better way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Limiting string input
const unsigned int STRINGCONSTRAINT = 255;

// Person struct to store name and numbers
typedef struct {
  char name[STRINGCONSTRAINT];
  char numbers[STRINGCONSTRAINT];
} person;

void getNameNumber(person people[], int size);
void printNumber(person people[], int size, char personFind[]);

// Asked for array's size and a person's name to find
int main(void) {
  unsigned int size = 0;
  printf("Enter the amount of people: ");
  scanf(" %d", &size);

  person people[size];
  getNameNumber(people, size);

  char personFind[STRINGCONSTRAINT];
  puts("Who do you want to find?");
  printf("Person to find: ");
  scanf(" %[^\n]s", personFind);

  printNumber(people, size, personFind);

  return 0;
}

// Get name and numbers for the array
void getNameNumber(person people[], int size) {
  unsigned int i;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", people[i].name);
    printf("Numbers: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", people[i].numbers);
  }
}

// Find the person and print the numbers
void printNumber(person people[], int size, char personFind[]) {
  unsigned int i;
  int flag = 1;

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    flag = strcmp(people[i].name, personFind);
    if (flag == 0) {
      puts("Found!");
      printf("You can call %s at %s.\n", personFind, people[i].numbers);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `static` functions

Both of your `getNameNumber` and `printNumber` should be made `static`, because I doubt that you plan to export them.

### Simpler functions

```
printf("Enter the amount of people: ");
```

can simply use `puts`, which doesn't have any formatting code in it. You use `puts` below, so this would also help with consistency.

### Stack allocation

```
person people[size];
```

is not available in all versions of C, since `size` is not a constant. For best portability you'd want to `malloc` this, or perhaps `alloca` if you feel strongly that the memory should be in the stack and not on the heap.

### `const`

`printNumber`'s array arguments should be `const`, since you don't mutate them.

### Your questions

> To avoid a very long name that exceeds char's size, I limit it to 255. Is there a better way?

For your use case, not really. A fixed array is the most appropriate. *However*, your code is vulnerable to overflows. You should be putting a width in your [format specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

> To avoid buffer, I included a space before % sign and not use getchar(). Is there a better way?

I'm not sure which usage of `%` you're referring to, but they all look fairly sane, so no; there's not really a better way.

Comment: "*is not available in all versions of C, since size is not a constant*". VLA available in C99 and since C11 compiler might not support VLA (in this case macro constant `__STDC_NO_VLA__` equals 1).

Comment: Wasn't `puts` the function that adds a newline, in contrast to `fputs`? Therefore it is not a good replacement for this `printf` call.

Comment: "can simply use puts" --> not same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

**Strange format**

The `s` in `scanf(" %[^\n]s", personFind)` serves no purpose.  Use `" %[^\n]"` instead

... or better, use a width limit. See [scanf / field lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301451/2410359)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this line:

> ```
>   scanf(" %d", &size);
> ```

We throw away the return value from this function, which means we have no way of knowing whether a value was written to `size`.  In this case, we don't have undefined behaviour, because we initialised it to zero before calling `scanf()`, but that's not the case later in the program where we read strings into uninitialized memory.  In any case, it's rude to users to silently change invalid input into a default answer, rather than giving a meaningful error message.

BTW, the space at the beginning of that conversion is redundant - numeric conversions always skip leading whitespace.